# How can I solve this constant value 5 using inverse Laplace?

Tags: inverse-laplace

I'm having a hard time understanding this problem. Please help me to solve this problem

> Evaluate $\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{5 + \frac s{s^2+9}\right\}$

https://i.ibb.co/TK3jbqK/Screenshot-2022-06-28-014247.png

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's literally the definitions of inverse Laplace. No calculations are needed. The answer is

\begin{align}
5 \delta (t) + \cos (3t)
\end{align}